# google analytics query explorer 2 username and account profile details are not populated

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

google analytics query explorer username and account profile details are not populated automatically. and geetting `401 : Login Required` error when trying to hit on **GET Data** even though i have logged in already.

Can any one help me in the steps to follow for creating google analytics account.

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

[image]

Comment: We have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I get very strange behaviour on the query explorer too at the moment.

Haven't found a way to log in to any of my GA accounts to generate a URI yet..